# FTPing to a remote directory

Tags: shell-script

I need to connect to this ftp http://cdiac.ornl.gov/ftp/ndp026b/ and download the files.

I did ftp http://cdiac.ornl.gov/ftp/ndp026b/ and it took the ftp prompt but once I entering commands for example `pwd`, it says `not connected`.

How can I connect to this directory?

Comment: I don't understand your question?  Are you saying you are restricted from accessing this site and want us to help you do this?  From the limited information you have provided me, it looks to me to be some type of firewall issue that needs to be addressed by either your local administrator or the remote administrator.  Please provide more information on the circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect using a command line ftp program you need to just name the host from after the command line rather than an http URL, like:

```
$ ftp hostname
```

You will then need to login, even for anonymous access. Here is an example session:

```
myuser$ ftp cdiac.ornl.gov
Connected to cdiac.ornl.gov.

Name (cdiac.ornl.gov:myuser): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password: anonymous@ornl.gov
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> bye
221 Goodbye.
```

You will need to navigate to the directory ftp/ndp026b.

The URL http://cdiac.ornl.gov/ftp/ndp026b/ is for use in a browser if you wish to access the files that way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to actually download the files there, and not just connect to the directory, you can use `wget`:

```
wget -r http://cdiac.ornl.gov/ftp/ndp026b/
```